Cloudfront does not want to clear cache
We have a cloudfront that has a default behavior that points to an s3 bucket for years, with few other behaviors as well with different origins, but now, we wanted to add a new origin, this origin will point to a custom URL(API), but the problem is, no matter what I try, clkoudfront keeps forwarding me to the s3 which I believe is because this new behavior was included in the default behavior before this, I tried changing origins and adding new behaviors to test things out, all new behaviors are ignored and cloudfront treats them as the default behavior for some reason, I did try invalidating with "/*" but it does not want to forget the cache ... I'm really baffled as to why this is happening.
